# How to find the amount of data that is transferred when I make a web service call from my android app?

Tags: android, web-services

I want to check the size of data that is being  transferred when my Android app makes a web service call. Is there any tool for that?

Answer (score 2):

Well in the HTTP response you have the `Content-Length` header which is the size of the payload in bytes. Thats half the battle, you'll need to calculate how much of your outgoing payload is (if you care).

Answer (score 2):

TrafficStats: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

You have to see if it can report data per UID though. Otherwise it may just report data usage of the entire system.